# flowLayout Panel is showing visibility false even its true in vb2005

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, flowlayoutpanel

flowLayoutPanel is showing visibility false even its true

when i run the form 1st time i get its  visibility & its actually visible

but the problem occurs when i close the form & again i open it from another form 
( at run-time w/o

closing project) its visibility shows false in msgbox but in actually its visible true

```
flwPnl.Visible=True
msgbox(flwPnl.Visible.tostring)
```

the value in msgbox on second time load is "False"

Please help!!!!!!

Comment: Do you set it to false anywhere?

Comment: The code snippet is not adequate to demonstrate the problem.  A key feature of the Visible property is that it doesn't return the value that you assigned to it, it tells you whether the control is actually visible to the user.  It won't be if the Parent is not visible for example.  For all we know, you might be using the wrong form reference.

Comment: the parent control is also visible & flowlayout is also visible  but it showing false value in msgbox